# Hyper-V enhance mode 19.04

Tags: hyper-v

I have been running Ubuntu 18.04 in Hyper-V with enhanced mode ever since it was introduced to the "Quick Create" menu and it has worked great.  In May Ubuntu announced support for 19.04 https://ubuntu.com/blog/19-04-disco-dingo-now-available-as-optimised-desktop-image-for-hyper-v .  When I try to install 19.04 from the "Quick Create" the enhanced mode options are not available.  Any ideas?

Comment: We are aware of this issue and have spoken with the Hyper-V team at Microsoft about it but it has proven difficult to pin down the cause. Can you please tell us what edition and build of Windows you are on? If I told you what we needed, would you be willing to collect some logs and diagnostics for us to compare? Thanks, Hayden Barnes
Developer Advocate for Ubuntu on WSL and Hyper-V

Comment: I am on the stable channel of Windows Pro 1903 build 18362.418.  I certainly can provide you with whatever information you require to help solve this.

Comment: I do have a 19.10 image working with enhanced services that I upgraded from 19.04 at some point while it worked.

Comment: I'm also on Pro 1903 18362.418 and not able to get enhanced session working for 19.04 via Quick Create

Comment: I guess that WSL is more important than this.

Comment: Goodbye Hyper-V and WSL.  Hello VMWare Workstation.

Comment: I decided against going for VMWare and created my own Hyper-V Ubuntu installation based on Ubuntu server and XFCE4 using the X410 XServer for windowed apps which has been working great.  I then decided to give Quick Create another shot out of curiosity and noticed 19.04 is no longer available as an option.  Only 18.04 (LTS) exists.  I guess it was to do it being EOL in January but to not have it replaced with 19.10 seems harsh.  I guess maybe they are going to stick to LTS releases to possibly avoid these issues.

Answer (score 9):

Switching to the Hyper-V optimized kernel fixed this for me:

```
sudo apt install linux-azure
```

(I also removed the old kernel with `sudo apt autoremove --purge` but that might not be important.) Then a restart is necessary. When it came back up it went into enhanced mode.

I'm on Windows 10 version 1909 build 18363.535. I installed Ubuntu 19.04 with "Quick Create" and have not upgraded it to 19.10.

Comment: Hi Mike,  I ust created a fresh 19.04 with Quick Create and installed linux-azure and now that machine won't even boot.

Comment: I just tried it 2 more times.  The second time it worked.

Comment: I tried again and it failed.  Something strange is going on here.  I am going to save the logs and see if I can get it to work again and compare them.

Comment: After trying this my Ubuntu 19.4 VM no longer connects

Comment: This did the trick for me :) for all, just remind to NOT activate auto-login (if activated you'll have de-activate then reboot). Also, I previously installed this : https://github.com/microsoft/linux-vm-tools Don't know if there's a link.

Comment: Worked for me for 19.10. Thanks!